# How to add whitespaces to json_encode function?

Tags: python, php, json, whitespace

I run json_encode (PHP 8.0.15) and it will return: `{"test":[0.1,0.2],"test2":"Hello World"}`.
When I use jsom.dumps (Python 3.8.6) it will return: `{"test": [0.1, 0.2], "test2": "Hello World"}`. Seems like PHP doesn't add whitespaces but I need them, because I need to rebuild the exact string and compare them.

Comment: "because I need to rebuild the exact string and compare them"—this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Why does it matter if the strings are exactly the same?

Comment: Note that [JSON objects aren't ordered](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), so even if you add or remove whitespace you aren't guaranteed the same strings. `{"foo": "", "bar": ""}` is exactly the same as `{"bar":"",    "foo"   : ""}`.

Comment: @Chris If the string exists in my DB it should be deleted if I doesn't have the whitespaces it will not find them.

Comment: How are you storing these values? In what database? Are you using a JSON-aware field type?

Comment: @Chris It's a redis list, so just values no keys.

Comment: "so just values no keys"—where the values are JSON strings? I suggest you use something other than JSON. You cannot infer equality between two JSON strings by comparing them as strings. It's in the standard, [as linked above](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), my emphasis: "An object is an _unordered_ set of name/value pairs." At minimum, you'll need some kind of deterministic JSON-like spinoff.

Answer (score 1):

Converting to string is not a good way to compare data structures unless you have a fully deterministic algorithm that always produces the same normalised output for structures you consider identical. JSON is not such algorithm. It isn't just nitpicking about obscure format specs. Is it really okay for your application to have both arrays with `"test"` and `"test2"` in different order where everything else is identical? Is your application code designed to handle those as different?

If the sample you've shared is representative of what data structures you can expect, decoding JSON and applying a simple equality operator will render more reliable results than your current approach:

```
$a = '{"test":[0.1,0.2],"test2":"Hello World"}';
$b = '{"test": [0.1, 0.2], "test2": "Hello World"}';
$c = '{"test2":"Hello World", "test":[0.1,0.2]}';
$d = '{"test":[0.1,0.3],"test2":"Hello World"}';

$obj_a = json_decode($a);
$obj_b = json_decode($b);
$obj_c = json_decode($c);
$obj_d = json_decode($d);

var_dump($obj_a == $obj_b); // true (same keys and values, same order)
var_dump($obj_a == $obj_c); // true (same keys and values, different order)
var_dump($obj_a == $obj_d); // false (same keys, different values)
```

Reference: [object comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)

> When using the comparison operator (`==`), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values (values are compared with `==`), and are instances of the same class.

Beware that this may or may not work as expected with nested data structures.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I don't decode the JSON strings and compare them, because my Redis-DB has ~1m entries and it would be a performance killer. I'm trying to pack my arrays with MessagePack - seems like Python and PHP will generate the same string when using MessagePack instead JSON.